# Half of tikzcd diagram is missing

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

Half of a commutative diagram (`tikz-cd`) is missing in the output. The rendering tool is `pdflatex`. The problem occurs when:

1. The documentclass is standalone.
2. The `tikz-cd` diagram is embedded in a tikzpicture.

Example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzcd}
      A \arrow{r}{a} \arrow{d}{b} & B \arrow{d}{c} \\
      C \arrow{r}{d} & D
    \end{tikzcd}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: tikzcd diagram with missing half]

Apparently embedding a tikzcd diagram inside a tikzpicture environment introduces an unexpected indent that the standalone documentclass does not account for.

This is a problem for us, since we're using a setup to support tikzpictures in a vBulletin math forum. It recognizes `\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}` as the markers that define the picture, and replaces it with a .svgz picture. As a math forum we also want to support commutative diagrams from the `cd` tikzlibrary. Since that apparently requires a toplevel tikzcd environment that doesn't fit into the structure.

What is causing the unexpected indent? And more importantly, how can we ensure that the diagram is rendered properly? That is, how can we get rid of the unexpected indent while still embedding the commutative diagram in a tikzpicture environment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think that it is a good idea to use `tikzcd` inside `tikzpicture` because it is not in the spirit of tikz to have drawing "environments".

But if you really need it, you can define a new environment `scopecd` like this

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
% define new environment `scopcd`
\def\scopecd{\let\tikzpicture\scope\let\endtikzpicture\endscope\tikzcd}
\let\endscopecd\endtikzcd

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[blue!14] circle(2);
    \begin{scopecd}
      K \arrow{r}{a} \arrow{d}{b} & B \arrow{d}{c} \\
      C \arrow{r}{d} & D
    \end{scopecd}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note :** For me it is more natural to have in your forum different environments that can produce pictures ; `tikzpicture`, `pgfpicture`, `tikzcd`, ...

Answer (score 4):

The `tikzcd` environment is already a `tikzpicture`, you don't have to nest them.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}
      A \arrow{r}{a} \arrow{d}{b} & B \arrow{d}{c} \\
      C \arrow{r}{d} & D
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed, but we have a setup where every picture is a tikzpicture. And nesting or not, that shouldn't introduce an unexpected indent should it? Nor should it make the standalone documentclass fail.

Comment: nesting of `tikzpicture` (of any kind)  usually lead to unexpected behavior (as you experienced). never do this!

Comment: @IlikeSerena  Sorry, I don't completely understand, nesting tikzpicture may cause problems, this is one. If you are obliged to use `tikzpicture`, use a TikZ `matrix of math nodes` instead of a `tikzcd` environment.

Comment: @CarLaTeX, we support tikzpictures in a vBulletin math forum. It recognizes `\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}` as the markers that define the picture, and replaces it with a .svgz picture. As a math forum we also want to support commutative diagrams from the 'cd' tikzlibrary. Since that apparently requires a toplevel tikzcd environment that doesn't fit into the structure.

Comment: @IlikeSerena can't you just adapt your forum code to recognise tikzd and treat it like tikzpicture?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, yes, that should be possible, although that has quite an impact on the whole infrastructure, which seems unwarranted to support just this one type of diagram. I didn't realize that the whole tikz environment would be nested. Is there perhaps a different way to use a diagram from the cd library so that it is not a nested tikzpicture?

Comment: @IlikeSerena well yes of course just don't nest it. Given that currently you are explicitly nesting one inside the other then it's hard to avoid nesting other that just "don't do that" of course tex being tex you could redefine tikzpicture to check for tikcd and do nothing in that case but it's bound to break something and if your forum code is using tex syntax it's best to use valid tex syntax rather than redefine tex to fit

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I've just checked the tikzcd package documentation, and apparently there is no alternative. That is, the only option it offers is a tikzcd environment. And I'm guessing that includes both a tikzpicture and a tabular environment, which is a bit unexpected. That is, afaik no other tikz related environment includes the tikzpicture environment.

Comment: @IlikeSerena The `tikzcd` environment is a `tikzpicture` with a `\matrix[matrix of math nodes]`.

Comment: I've investigated the suggested work-arounds (new tikzcd marker, redefinition of tikzpicture, use of matrix of math nodes). My conclusion is that they are all unfortunately a bit awkward. Still, the only real problem I have, is the unexpected indent. Where is it coming from? Can we get rid of it?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I found a possible fix by editing `tikz-cd/tikzlibrarycd.code.tex`. If I replace `\tikzpicture` and `\endtikzpicture` by `\scope` respectively `\endscope`, the code works as desired. Of course it breaks the original behavior. Is there perhaps a way to detect we're already inside a tikzpicture environment and only make that change then?

Comment: `\@currenvir` will be tikzpicture inside a tikzpicture environment  (you can redefine macros without editing the original sources)

Comment: @IlikeSerena An ugly workaround is to include your `tikzcd` in a `node` like this `\node{\begin{tikzcd}...\end{tikzcd}};`

Comment: Thank you @Kpym, a node around it indeed solves the problem. And it's something that I can explain to the members of the math forum. That is pending a better solution where the tikzcd macro is somehow tweaked to be smart enough to handle that it's already inside a tikzpicture environment, which I'm still trying to figure out.

Comment: @IlikeSerena Why just not configure your forum to recognize `tikzcd` as "synonym" of `tikzpicture` and treat it like a picture ?

Comment: @Kpym, that should work as well, but I'm not particularly in favor of impacting the infrastructure for just a single package that just happens to be intolerant for its environment. What will the next such package be? It seems better to me if the packages are flexible enough to function within a tikzpicture environment as they should. And if they don't, we just need to make them more flexible. At present it's only tikzcd that is inflexible, and I'm hoping we can fix that one way or another.